# How to make Ubuntu Touch run at normal speed with screen turned off?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, performance

It seems that Ubuntu Touch (Vivid on Nexus 5) goes into an extremely slow (power-saving?) scheduling mode when the touch sensor has been idle for long enough for the screen to turn off.

This makes the phone unusable for running compilers and benchmarks over ssh, which happens to be my use case.

Is there a way to tell Ubuntu Touch to run the scheduler in the same mode as when the screen is awake when the screen isn't awake but I'm using the phone over ssh?